# I am new to drools. Is there any documents or videos I can use for reference

Tags: spring-boot, drools, kie, drools-planner

I am new to the Drools rule engine. Is there any good document, website or blog which will help me develop a full-fledged project of Drools using spring boot. I am also planning to use UI to generate .drl files

Comment: https://www.drools.org/

Answer (score 1):

- Official Documentation - https://www.drools.org/learn/documentation.html
- Getting Started tutorials - http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-jbpm/drools
- Youtube tutorial - https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLZnMNSr-VrIgiqhYYCO-OW1frUEDrSpid
- Random drools tutorials playlist - https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLE0Bp2jOdLFJfYLCrWSpip8OYsbH46fsN
- Drools.next: Vision, Roadmap, Updates on 7 .x Releases - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kKeTA08M8ko
- Mastering JBoss Drools 6 book.

Answer (score 1):

As Drools is the community upstream of Red Hat Decision Manager (RHDM), I'd also recommend reviewing the [Red Hat documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_decision_manager/7.3/) in addition to the official [drools docs](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/latest/drools-docs/html_single/index.html) pointed out by other commentators.
Within the Red Hat docs you should find sections on Rule Authoring within the UI (Business Central) as well as helpful examples if using an IDE.  Example projects that are referenced by both the community and RHDM docs are located in a [master Github repo](https://github.com/kiegroup/drools/tree/master/drools-examples).

For Spring Boot specifically, RHDM docs also contain a guide titled [Creating Red Hat Decision Manager business applications with Spring Boot](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_decision_manager/7.3/html/creating_red_hat_decision_manager_business_applications_with_spring_boot/), this should give you a good starting point with an app generator at https://start.jbpm.org/